# Performance method audit with spring, aspectj and annotation based

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, aspectj

I have a question about how to do an time performance audit over a method using annotations, aspectj and spring

basically I have:

```
 public class MyClass{

 @TimeAudit
 public myMethod(){
  //do something
 }
}
```

i want to just log(or just print it in console) somewhere the time spent for that method to be executed. My problem is how an aspect will intercept that annotation and after that count the time that method spent.

How i can do that?
to clarify a little bit my question:
I have the annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface TimeAudit {

}
```

i have my aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PerformanceTimeExecutionAudit {

     @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(timeAudit)")
     public Object doLogTime(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, TimeAudit timeAudit) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("Start time..."+System.currentTimeMillis());
    Object output = pjp.proceed();
    System.out.println("End time..."+System.currentTimeMillis());

    return output;
}
}
```

on other class:

```
 @Repository
 public class MyClass{ 
 @Override
 @TimeAudit
  public void myMethod(){
    //do something
   }
 }
```

but the aspect is not triggered for that method were i put @TimeAudit. 
What i do wrong?

Comment: [Perf4J](http://www.infoq.com/articles/perf4j).

Comment: thank you for that, it seems to do that performance measurement. But i want to see how i can do it.

Comment: You could check the [Perf4J source code](https://github.com/perf4j/perf4j).  The `@Profiled` annotation is in the `aop` package.  This triggers a `ProfiledTimingAspect` that is also in the same package.  From here you can follow the code to how the actual measurement and logging is handled.  The AspectJ configuration is on the page I linked to above.

Comment: Have you enabled AOP in your Spring configuration?  How is the application configured?

Comment: yes .... xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd      
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

Comment: And AspectJ RT is on the classpath, you have posted actual code and so on?  Post this entire code on Github as a Gist for someone to take a look at.

Comment: Well after hours of debugging and so on i discovered that i am a dumb  head :) I had a spring bean header but it didn't scanned my @Aspect package ... because i missed that ... after i changed to scan also my Aspect package it worked very well. Thank you for the great support that you gave me ...

Comment: Please write your own answer containing the Spring configuration and accept it in order to close the question or just delete the question - whatever seems more appropriate to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise a short tutorial how to create an aspect in conjunction with Annotation to be useful for newcomers in this area.

1. you need the library dependencies:
   aspectjrt
   aspectjweaver
   spring-aop
   along with others spring dependencies like spring context etc.

2 Create your Annotation example:

```
 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
 public @interface TimeAudit {
  //put here whatever fields you need
 }
```

3 Create your aspect, example:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PerformanceTimeExecutionAudit {

 @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(TimeAudit)")
 public Object doLogTime(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, TimeAudit timeAudit) throws Throwable {

   System.out.println("Start time..."+System.currentTimeMillis());
   Object output = pjp.proceed();
    //this is with @Around, you can use in your asspect all others annotations like @Before, @After etc. this depends on your logic behavior.
   System.out.println("End time..."+System.currentTimeMillis());

   return output;
 }
}
```

4 On your your methods use your annotation like this - A little observations is that you can create the Annotation to behave as you want.

```
@Repository
public class MyClass{ 
 @Override
 @TimeAudit 
 public void myMethod(){
   //do something
 }
} 
//- this @TimeAudit can contain params, this depends on your Annotation  logic creation
```

5. be sure your spring context is scanning your packages where you have the Aspect, and also the package where you have the class annotated. Or you can declare them as beans in spring context configuration.
6. Be sure that you enabled the AOP. You need something like this in your spring config:

   ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <beans xmlns="........
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation=".........
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
   ```

That's it. 
I hope it will be useful for someone.